# How to make an object go to a higher layer

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want this to be on top... how can I do this and not have it go underneath...

http://opentech.durhamcollege.ca/~intn2201/brittains/chatter/signup_step2.php

I think there is a way in CSS to make stuff go on higher layers I think I read something about it a few years ago but I forget what its called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index)